# Way to thank the diamond moderators?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, moderators

I'd like to have a way to thank the diamond moderators. My proposal: Once a year, maybe a month before the new elections begin<sup>1</sup>,  we get a virtual box where anyone can put some multiple of 50 rep in up to 500, similiar to bounties. The total amount in the box will be split evenly between the moderators at that time. Note that it is completely up to a user whether they put in anything.

Why I think this is a good idea: Diamond Moderation takes a lot of time on the bigger sites. This is time they also could have spent in writing answers and gaining rep, or doing completely other things. They only get one golden badge. So it is pretty thankless job. I feel that it be should rewarded in some way.

Further, rep is a measurement of how much we trust an user. If a moderator resigns, then the diamond is gone and no sign of how much we trusted the user – unless we give him a fat rep bonus.

<sup>1</sup> Because that is mostly when moderators start resigning. These moderators also served for almost a year, so should be eligible for the bonus.

Comment: You might consider writing a comment why this is such a bad idea?

Comment: Feature request + downvote = disagreement with the idea usually

Comment: If a moderator resigns they get a [sheriff badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/208/sheriff)

Comment: And above all it is not a thankless *job*, they are still volunteers. If they don't like what they are doing they won't last long I guess...

Comment: @rene: they get the badge when serving at least a year, not when / because they resign.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so you do nothing from now on, and still get the badge. How unfair... ;)

Comment: I prefer steaks, beer, and cash.

Comment: I would note that elections tend to be held _because_ moderators resign, not the other way around.

Comment: Being called a nazi on the regular was always enough to keep me warm.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I am not a moderator, nor do I play one on TV.

However, I have a bit of insight having being a candidate in an election, the motives for performing moderator duties are not for any particular reward, but to more actively ensure the continued success of the site(s) that they moderate. This is a major strength - that the moderators are chosen by their community for their *demonstrated* passion for the community(ies) that they are part of.

Further, if a 'bonus' were introduced, then that would potentially result in candidates with a nonconstructive motivation (of gaining a rep bonus) - potentially resulting in a dilution of the effectiveness of moderation - there are already too many obsessed with gaining rep (e.g. through bad edits etc).

How to thank moderators? A note on the site's meta or chat perhaps, but the best way is to work *with* the moderators.

But the continued success of the site and the community's participation is often 'reward' enough.

*and for the record, I am very appreciative of the work the moderators have done and do*

Comment: I am a moderator and I approve this message.

Comment: Me too. I _really_ don't care about reputation.